# Office 365 developer account

Tags: office365

How to create a Office 365 developer account?

I tried to signup from http://dev.office.com/ but I don't understand how to get an account for starting to use api, graph, etc...

Anyone could help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create an Office 365 account. You can sign up for [an Office 365 Developer subscription](https://portal.office.com/Signup/Signup.aspx?OfferId=6881A1CB-F4EB-4db3-9F18-388898DAF510&DL=DEVELOPERPACK&ali=1#0) that includes the resources that you need to start building Office 365 apps.

> **Note**: If you already have a subscription, the previous link sends you to a page with the message *Sorry, you can’t add that to your current account*. In that case, use an account from your current Office 365 subscription.

- Get a Microsoft Azure tenant to register your application. Azure Active Directory (AD) provides identity services that applications use for authentication and authorization. A trial subscription can be acquired here: [Microsoft Azure](https://account.windowsazure.com/SignUp).

> **Important**: You also need to make sure your Azure subscription is bound to your Office 365 tenant. To do this, see the Active Directory team's blog post, [Creating and Managing Multiple Windows Azure Active Directories](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/11/08/creating-and-managing-multiple-windows-azure-active-directories.aspx). The section **Adding a new directory** will explain how to do this. You can also see [Set up your Office 365 development environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/setup-development-environment#bk_CreateAzureSubscription) and the section **Associate your Office 365 account with Azure AD** to create and manage apps for more information.